# О взаимосвязи hashCode() и equals(). Правильно ли я ее понимаю?

Tags: java, hashcode, equals

hashCode возвращает целочисленное int, которое характеризует объект. Грубо говоря, если у объекта есть два целочисленных поля, то мы должны как-то засунуть их в hashcode. Например, перемножить. Но засунуть нужно так, чтобы как можно меньшее количество других наборов переменных могло совпадать. 
И вот, у нас есть hashCode. Если объекты равны, то логично, что и hashCode'ы должны быть равны. Но если hashCode'ы равны, то объекты не обязательно должны быть равны, ведь мы не можем впихнуть все значения полей в одну переменную int, так?

Значит, если hashCode'ы равны, то шанс того, что объекты равны, очень сильно(зависит от того, как грамотно мы напишем алгоритм метода hashCode) повышается. А если они не равны, то объекты и вовсе не могут быть равны.

Мы знаем, что метод equals очень много жрет(так как сравнивает все поля объектов). Поэтому вместо использования equals для каждого сравнения мы сначала используем ОЧЕНЬ(относительно) дешевую операцию сравнения hashcode'ов объектов, которая ОЧЕНЬ повышает шанс того, что объекты равны. И только потом производим операцию сравнения equals, чтобы сказать точно об их идентичности.

Именно так и поступают коллекции HashMap, HashTable, HashSet.

Все ли так, как я написал?

Comment: всё так, суть состоит именно в этом)

Comment: Существует такое понятие как контракт этих методов. Он должен соблюдаться. По поводу того, что `equals()` много жрет, то далеко не всегда мы вначале проверяем равенство хеш-кодов. Я видел такой подход только при работе с хеш-таблицами. И еще - в контракт метода `equals()` входит согласованность с методом `compareTo()`, если речь идет о `Comparable`- объекте

Comment: суть не в том, что equals() много жрет, а в том, что коллекции set и map используются для поиска деревья (бинарное, красно-черное...), таким образом, им не нужно перебирать все элементы для поиска  , как это приходится делать в списках (листах). считайте, что hashCode - это аналог айдишника базы данных для хешированных таблиц

Comment: да, Comparable- объекты никакого отношения к этому не имеют. контракт equals() и hashcode() существует именно потому, что хешированные таблицы используют оба эти метода. компараторы - совсем не из этой оперы. они определяют порядок сортировки. и для одного объекта компараторов с разной логикой можно создать сколько угодно (так и делают, если нужна разная логика сортировки объектов одного типа). это никак не влияет на использование таких объектов в хешированных таблицах

Comment: @Дмитрий порылся, действительно, с помощью hashcode определяют хитрым алгоритмом его "id". То есть не нужно перерывать все ключи, чтобы найти места совпадения. Очень хитро, очень хитро.
Но по сути equals не факт, что медленней, так как там происходит проверка на принадлежность к классу, а потом уже последовательная проверка переменных(при несовпадении сразу возвращает false). А в hashcode для каждого хитро вычисляется число, а потом эти числа сравниваются. Так что, тут еще вопрос, зачем нужен hashCode, кроме как не для имитации "id" в hashMap.

Comment: @Дмитрий, я не говорю про компаратор. Только про `Comparable` - его метод `compareTo()` толжен быть согласован с `equals()`. Читайте матчасть! Если `equals()` двух объектов возвращает `true`, то `compareTo()` должен возвращать `0` для этих объектов. И это входит в контракт `equals()`, ведь мы о нем в том числе говорим...

Comment: @Дмитрий, поиск по бинарным деревьям как раз происходит с помощью интерфейсов `Comparable` (если элементы коллекции его имплементируют), или с помощью `Comparator`-a. Поэтому в таком случае и важна связь `equals()` c `Comparable#compareTo()`. Для `Comparator`-a это нереализуемо, поэтому про него не идет речь

Comment: я и не говорил, что equals медленный. вопрос "О взаимосвязи hashCode() и equals()". к этой взаимосвязи Comparable никак не относится. у него другое назначение. для работы деревьев важны 2 метода и существует только 3 варианта развития событий. 1)hashCode разный-элементы разные, пишутся в разные бакеты.2 )hashCode одинаковый и equals() одинаковый, тогда элемент перезаписывается.3)hashCode одинаковый и equals() рзный - элементы с одним хешкодом попадают в один бакет. где здесь Comparable? если вы используете какой-то TreeSet,то это специфика конкретной коллекции, а не хешированых таблиц в целом

Comment: для примера, вот вам сорцы хешмепа public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>     implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable { где здесь Comparable?

Comment: @Дмитрий, вы сами запутались и людей путаете. В деревьях не используется хешкод. Он используется в хеш-таблицах включая сет и мап. Деревья используют метод compareTo для сравнения элементов или компаратор, если его передали в конструкторе. Очевидно, вы опечатались и пишете про хеш таблицы, а не про деревья... А связь иквалса с компейрТу просто прописана в контракте иквалса. А топикстартер спрашивает, ничего ли он не упустил.

Comment: я вам распиал, каким образом работают hashCode() и equals() для всех коллекций типа Set и Map и я так и не услышал, какую роль здесь играет compareTo(). объясните , как переопределение этого метода влияет на работу HashSet и все станет на свои места. если можете привести другой пример работы hashCode() и equals() (кроме коллекций), тоже не возражаю...

Comment: Да почитайте вы свои моменты! Вы пишете то про хешмап, то про деревья... В деревьях он используется! Не хешкод, а именно компэйрТу или компаратор